# how can i get data from js?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

[site](https://www.scopus.com/hirsch/author.uri?accessor=authorProfile&auidList=55070669000&authorName=Rajabiun%2C%20Reza&origin=AuthorProfile&txGid=7e1b575a2b93b60302df5b156ddfabdb/)

this html is 'Update Graph' button

```
<button type="button" id="updateGraphButton_submit1" name="authEvalUpdate" class="btn btn-primary fontNormal">  
     <span> class="btnText">Update Graph</span>  
</button>
```

i want submit '2017' instead of second 2009, on this web site.
[image: site img]

so i try analyzing js.

https://www.scopus.com/gzip_85909950/bundles/AuthorEvaluatorBottomMaster.js

and i found this code.

```
jQuery('#authHirschPage').on('click','#updateGraphButton_submit1',AuthEval.updateResults);
```

i'm confident that this button is related to the above. but still have no idea how submit these values that get 2009~2017 's graph.

Comment: So, select 2017 in the dropdwon?

Comment: @adiga yes, i try 'find_elements_by_xpath' and  .click() but it can't select when dropdown is out of view range.

Comment: Can you please share the html of the second list box (to) and it's list items div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sang oh, hi. Didnt manage to find same dropdowns - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLTIC.png as in Your page.

Suggesting the following solution here:

1) You should click on second dropdown

2) wait until values are appeared there

3) select 2017 (or any other Year value You need)

4) And submit the page.

Alternatively, You may be executing JavaScript  and Webdriver select APIs to select dropdown values.

For example:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('year').style.display='block';");

//Then Select required value
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("year")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("2017");
```

Provided You have page HTML smth like:

```
<select class="selectBox" id="year" name="year" size="1" style="display: none;">
<option value="">Select Year</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option> 
<option value="2012">2012</option> 
.......
</select>
```

Comment: i'm sorry that have lack of description. i access this site on my collage computer. so generally, you have no permission to see this site.